# Unsuccessful Download using DownloadManager in Android 9

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager

I have an xls file in my server which needs to be downloaded in my phone using an apps. I'm using Nokia 5 and Android 9 for testing. My compile sdk version is 29. When I clicked download button, it didn't do anything, and after waiting for a while, a "Download Unsuccessful" notification popped up.

This is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PERMISSION_STORAGE_CODE = 1000;
    EditText editUrl;
    Button btnDownload;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editUrl = findViewById(R.id.edit_url);
        btnDownload = findViewById(R.id.btn_download);

        btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                        String [] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                        requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_STORAGE_CODE);
                    }
                    else {
                        startDownloading();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    startDownloading();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void startDownloading() {
        String url = editUrl.getText().toString().trim();

        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
        request.setTitle("Download");
        request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
      request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, ""+System.currentTimeMillis());
        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        manager.enqueue(request);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch(requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_STORAGE_CODE: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
                    startDownloading();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added network_security_config.xml (domain is blurred for security reason)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">moneytracker.mauini******.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

and added it in manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.main.downloadtest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

And lastly, the download url is something like this:

> http://moneytracker.mauini******.com/uploads/asd.xls

The file is successfully downloaded when that URL is executed in browser.

Am I missing something? Those are all I can get, searching for days. Please help.

Comment: did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First, on your code `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, ""+System.currentTimeMillis());`. After `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS` param, you should put correct file name on it. `coolfilename.xxx`. Or, get its Uri value and put the `Uri.getLastPathSegment()` as the second parameter. Second, try to put `request.setMimeType(param)`.